# Django Queryset Occurences Counts

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have the following django model...

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    entry_UUID = models.UUIDField()                                                                     
    entry_description = models.TextField()
    numeric_value = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True) 
    entry_category = models.CharField()
```

I am trying to query the database - I expect groups of entry_UUIDs and for each group some statistics for numeric_value (Min/Max/Avg) and counts for entry_category. I won't know the specific values for entry_category ahead, but I expect them to form a set (ex. {low, med, high}).

I have tried the following query:

```
Entry.objects.filter(
            entry_UUID__in = entry_UUIDs).values(
                'entry_UUID').annotate(
                    Avg('numeric_value'), 
                    Min('numeric_value'), 
                    Max('numeric_value'), 
                    Count('entry_category'))
```

Which returns...

```
<QuerySet [{'entry_UUID': UUID('9fcfea6d-9480-595f-1e1f-81130ddc0c99'), 'numeric_value__avg':
51.5089, 'numeric_value__min': 23.174, 'numeric_value__max': 76.421, 'entry_category__count': 4}, {'entry_UUID': UUID('9fcfea6d-9490-595f-1e1f-81130ddc0c99'), 'numeric_value__avg': 5.2882, 'numeric_value__min': 1.282, 'numeric_value__max': 9.7553, 'entry_category__count': 6}]>
```

For entry_category I am looking to get counts of occurences for each value rather that a total count. Not sure how to got about this.

Thanks.

Comment: Does the 'entry_category__count' is coming wrong, it seems like right. And if it is wrong according to you, want the expected output

Comment: What I am looking for is in the same query a count of occurences for entry_category ( ex. {'entry_category': 'green', 'entry_category__count': 1}, {'entry_category': 'red', 'entry_category__count': 2}. Rather than a total count ex. 'entry_category__count': 3

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need can be achieved using this

```
Entry.objects.filter(
            entry_UUID__in = entry_UUIDs).values(
                'entry_UUID', 'entry_category').annotate(
                    Avg('numeric_value'), 
                    Min('numeric_value'), 
                    Max('numeric_value'), 
                    Count('entry_category'))
```